# Is there such thing as a SELECT with an IF/ELSE statement in mySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

**Is it possible to have a SELECT statement in mySQL with an IF/ELSE clause in it?**

E.g.

I want to SELECT all table rows and return color2 ONLY if color2 is 'brown'.  My example SQL select statement of what I would like to accomplish is below.

```
APPLES
+------+--------+----------+----------+  
|  ID  |  NAME  |  COLOR1  |  COLOR2  |  
+------+--------+----------+----------+  
|  1   | apple1 |    red   |   brown  |
+------+--------+----------+----------+  
|  2   | apple2 |    red   |   green  |
+------+--------+----------+----------+
```

SELECT name, (IF color2 = 'brown' SELECT color2 ELSE SELECT color1) AS color FROM apples

would return:

```
+----------+----------+
|  apple1  |   brown  |
+----------+----------+
|  apple2  |    red   |
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL has an [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function:

```
SELECT name, IF(color2='brown', color2, color1) AS color FROM apples
```

Comment: Thanks ChssPly76.  I have a follow up question here.  I'm trying to use that new table column (colour) to join another table but the join is giving me this error: Unknown column 'color' in 'on clause'.  Any ideas?

Comment: i posted the follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642147/how-can-i-use-a-mysql-select-if-statement-row-to-join-another-table.  someone has answered it already.  thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
SELECT a.name, 
       CASE WHEN a.color2 = 'brown' THEN a.color2 ELSE a.color1 END AS color 
  FROM apples a
```

Reference: [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)

The CASE statement allows for IF/ELSE or SWITCH-like functionality, and has the benefit of being ANSI standard.  That query would work on SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL...

Comment: Thanks Rexem. I have a follow up question here just like with ChssPly76. I'm trying to use that new table column (colour) to join another table but the join is giving me this error: Unknown column 'color' in 'on clause'. Any ideas?

Comment: i posted the follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642147/how-can-i-use-a-mysql-select-if-statement-row-to-join-another-table.  someone has answered it already.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the `CASE` statement in the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html).

Answer (score 2):

The [Control Flow Function documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/control-flow-functions.html) should help you.