# How can I use a mySQL SELECT IF statement row to JOIN another table?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I am using an IF statement in my mySQL SELECT statement and depending on the returned result from the IF statement I would like to join another table.

Eg.
SELECT name, IF(apple = 'brown', color1, color2) AS ripeness FROM apples JOIN apple_type ON apple_type.color = ripeness

My problem is that I am receiving the error msg: Unknown column 'ripeness' in 'on clause'.  Does anyone know how I can get around this to join the other table based on the result from the IF/ELSE in the Select clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to duplicate the `IF` call there. For example:

```
SELECT
    name,
    IF(apple = 'brown', color1, color2) AS ripeness
FROM
    apples
    JOIN apple_type ON apple_type.color = IF(apple = 'brown', color1, color2)
```

Comment: SELECT comments.* 
    
    FROM comments JOIN registered_domains 
    ON 
    comments.domain_id = registered_domains.domain_id 
    WHERE 
    comments.page_id = 446 
    AND 
    IF(registered_domains.`moderation`=0, 1, comments.moderated=1 )
     ORDER BY comment_index ASC;


Hello Lukás,

I was wondering if you could have a look at my SQL statement and understand what I am trying to do... because MySQL has no idea!! :D  
I am trying to put a where condition depending on the result of an IF Statement.   
Thanks for any help! 
cheers
Ali

Comment: as it turns out... I was working all along... thank you mate... cheers ... I like these three dots ... :P